# "ASK QUESTION" is not really obvious as a button

Tags: discussion, design

This has been mentioned a few times on the feedback threads. But never really addressed. So let's make it its own post. Because I find this to be problematic.

Because I am familiar with the sites, I know the ASK QUESTION option in the top right is going to be a button - it's always in that same position. But anyone who hasn't been on any other Stack Exchange site will not necessarily get this. It looks like it could just be a flying saucer that says ASK QUESTION, since this is a Q&A site after all. It could easily be thought of as a background element meant to oppose the logo and give the right side more flavour. Before the launch, people were concerned, but seeing it in reality kinda solidifies the issue for me.

It just needs to be more... button-like. Or since we're a gaming site, just make it something a bit more "menu choice like". Even the tabs, which are in similar style, they at least highlight when you hover over them. We just need something that makes it clear that you should click on it to ask a question. Because it's currently just too different from any of the normal interactive elements that it is too easily confused with the background.

Comment: I was just going to post this same thing.  I think it should have twice the height, with a more outstanding color and a larger font.  I also like the rollover idea.

Comment: We're getting _so many_ questions in the answer area right now it's pretty sad. I can't get actual numbers, but they're probably the #1 cause of flags right now.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Feature Request**: Make the Ask Question button start shooting lasers on mouseover.

## Lasers!

Comment: It actually already has a laser. But more lasers is always good.

Comment: Clearly I mean animated flashing lasers. That result in explosions. Point is, we need more lasers.

Comment: Can we add `cursor: pointer;` to the Ask button's CSS?

Comment: @JackM This Meta question is so dead and buried that you're better off posting a new answer or a new Meta question tagged [tag:feature-request]. Nobody but me will see it otherwhise.

Answer (score 17):

At bare minimum, it should change colors on mouse rollover (Like StackOverflow, SuperUser, etc.)

Webapps has the same problem of a static button, but it, at least, stands out from the background.

Comment: I like the mouseover idea

Comment: I like the idea of a little back lighting

Comment: i'll add a hover effect of some sort to be consistent with the rest of the tabs.

Comment: @Jin Is this still planned?  Because it still seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Jin commented on this [in chat](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6517#6517):

> regarding the ask button, i'd like to see how most people will use it as it is now. it's possible i may just move "ask question" as another tab like the others(but maybe a diff color)
>
> [Snip]
>
> i remember jeff mentioned to me a long time ago, he intentionally didn't emphasize the "ask question" link on SO is to discourage people ask right away, without searching for answers first
>   this way, it filters out some noise...

I have not carefully checked to see if I'm cutting out important context. You should check out that area of the transcript if you are interested.

Comment: +1 for as another tab, that would work well (perhaps with a different color and a small interior icon?)

Comment: @Jin other SE-2.0 site themes *do* have hover effects on that button.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that that button is intentionally not obvious as to avoid new users to start typing questions without first looking around.
This goes beyond the design, but I wanted to bring attention to that fact also.

In regards to the spaceship, I like it.

Comment: As long as it's more obvious that you can and should click it, the design is fine by me. But right now, it behaves roughly the same as the little spaceman and the satellite dish, neither of which do anything.

Comment: @Grace, yes, at the very least it should glow on mouse over like the tabs

Comment: Not to mention the bounds of the button itself are non-obvious