# Make the mothership shoot its lasers on hover

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

1. All trilogy sites, and almost all other SE2.0 sites, have a hover effect on their "ask question" button.
2. It can be argued the "ask question" button looks less "clickable" than how it looks in *all* the other family sites, it's very close to a decoration and thus really needs some way to emphasize its link-iness if a mouse cursor quickly passes over it.
3. Seriously... it's a spaceship. We're talking high awesomeness factor here.

I know many others want it. Come on guys... together, we can do it. Upvote this question until the vote count overflows, until Jin has no other choice!

**EDIT** I forgot it was suggested before, though not as a real feature-request; [original credits to LessPop](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/ask-question-is-not-really-obvious-as-a-button/1212#1212)!

Comment: Point 2 is kind of a [definite](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/ask-question-is-not-really-obvious-as-a-button/).

Comment: In fact it has been already suggested [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/ask-question-is-not-really-obvious-as-a-button/1212#1212)

Comment: @Drake indeed! I forgot about it, but it's anyway good that this gets a feature-request thread of its own!

Comment: It's been on my long list to do, I promise! I will dedicate one day as the Laserpewpew Day for this. Realistically, I can work it in within 2 weeks. If not, keep bugging me.

Comment: @Jin you asked, so this is another bug.

Comment: @Jin It's over a month now. A laser-less month.

Comment: @Jin moar buggin'!

Comment: @Jin Did you just give up on this? :(

Comment: @Ullallulloo, no I haven't! I was out of town last week. And i have a pile of other design issues to work on. So for now I'm putting this on hold.

Comment: Yes, this would be cool!

Comment: @Jin this is your friendly neighborhood ping. No pressure, just to remind you we're still here :)

Comment: @Jin and a week later:  ditto what Oak said.  :)

Comment: @Jin: How are you?

Comment: Lazers! Pew Pew

Comment: @Jin I hear August is a great time for Laserpewpew Days.

Comment: @Jin I hear September is good. October is fine too. But September is better.

Comment: @fredley I heard a rumor that the mothership finally has collected enough crystals for its GN drives to fire the Mega Particle Beam Canon. Soon.

Comment: @Jin How soon is 'soon'?

Comment: @Jin The year is almost up!

Comment: @Jin All I want for Christmas...

Comment: @Jin Happy new year! ;)

Comment: @Jin Happy Epiphany! :)

Comment: It took me a second to figure out you're talking about CSS `:hover`.

Comment: @Jin Happy Pancake Day!

Comment: @Jin happy lasers day! Wee!

Comment: Seeing this finally tagged with "status-completed" is like a dream come true! :D Thanks @Jin!

Comment: @Jin Happy Laser Lovers' day!

Comment: It makes me fuzzy inside that I just gave this its 100th upvote!

Answer (score 32):

If we're going to go through with this, at least have it shooting something:

[image: Lazers]

This could be combined with @badp's idea too.

Comment: This looks super-lame now compared to the real thing - thanks @Jin!

Answer (score 19):

> [image: The mothership charges its lazers.] → [image: The mothership arms its lazers.] → [image: The mothership fires its lazers.]

Here's how the mothership could look like when firing its lazers. To compensate for the brightness of the sheer lazers our mothership is equipped with, the remainder of the page should dampen by 90%.

This is unfortunate, for the lazers look best against the scanlined effect.

Comment: -1, not enough [pixelation](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/bring-back-pixelation-a-how-to).

Comment: @Brant Our lazers are powerful enough that we *overcome the limits of the hardware we were written on*.

Comment: Does CSS support HDR?

Comment: -1, the rest of the page should dampen by 99% from the sheer incredibleness.

Comment: _Thou shalt not obscure text while doing totally sweet graphic effects_...?