# So I heard you like Magic cards

Tags: discussion, fun

After the people over at [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) made a promotional Magic card, I thought it would be fun to card-ify some of the people here.  They were apparently very popular (mostly) and people were asking for more.  So here are some of the cards I made.

If you want to make your own, just download [Magic Set Editor](http://magicseteditor.sourceforge.net/) and go to town!

Also, I cannot art.  If you can art, feel free to submit better arts.

Edit: Public set icon available at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4291332/SE.mse-symbol - just save it as a .mse-symbol file.

---

GROUND RULES

The goal of this kind of thing is for everyone to have fun and enjoy themselves. To that end we've come to agree with allowing it under the following circumstances, in addition to the standard rules explained in the [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) tag wiki.

1. Please do not make a card of a user without their permission.
2. Please do not make a card of a user with malicious or mocking intent. Even absent of such intent, if a user feels insulted or offended by their personal depiction, that depiction must be taken down.
3. Please be respectful of others in comments and do not turn this into pro-anti arguments about neither the card deal as a whole nor about subject matters depicted in cards.

Comment: Haha, they are very cool... and oddly accurate

Comment: [Meta](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7dSi9.jpg)

Comment: THESE ARE AMAZING. THESE ARE SO AWESOME! YOU GUYS ARE THE AWESOMEST

Comment: Where is the LoL promotion card?

Comment: @Blem - The horror...

Comment: Someone Magic-ify me!

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Comment: And yet the question has an odd number of votes!

Answer (score 22):

[image: The Ask Mothership]

But fortunately for us:

[image: Mass Effect 3]

Source - [Make the mothership shoot its lasers on hover](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover) (which was voted +81/-0 when this was made status-complete)

Comment: @Jin still waiting :3

Comment: I FEEL SO ASHAMED! SERIOUSLY!

Comment: @Jin you can still redeem yourself! I'm sure you can guess how ;)

Comment: cough cough cough

Comment: @Jin redeemed. =D

Comment: @Jin you deserved another card, so there!

Answer (score 21):

[image]

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Comment: I couldn't remove the cart number or do the fancy Stack Exchange thingy but oh well.

Comment: Man, green mana is **so** appropriate for my avatar.

Comment: Needs updated to re-un fallen it.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Jeff Atwood card]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Comment: science for the win!

Answer (score 8):

[image: spugsley card]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: sigh, sadly I'm still tapped because of this...

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: FAE Card]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Grace Note card]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Judge Ruling**: Consensus has no mana cost and can therefore never be cast.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]