# Make the meta mothership shoot its lasers too

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, mothership

The main site does it, why not the meta site?

Related:
[Make the mothership shoot its lasers on hover](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover)

Comment: For some reason I seem to think that Jin said they weren't going to do it on Meta ... but I could be hallucinating.

Comment: I feel as though the grey-scale colour theme lends itself to a "frozen-in-time" aspect which is further reinforced by the inanimate "ASK QUESTION" button. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=mDdOvhMszI4#t=9s Because meta discussions take a step back from the current situation, and evaluate it, preferably in (semi-)pause, Sims style, Fight Club style, Sherlock Holmes style, etc..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This was done as part of Stack Exchange's standardised site design rollout. Both main and meta-site motherships will now fire their lazors on page load, after a short delay.

Answer (score 16):

What if on meta the mothership fired lazer cannons firing lazers?

That'd be meta right??

Comment: +1 Totally makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

For now, this isn't a near-term goal. Jin is still our only designer and he's kinda... being torn apart by us dragging him to deal with everything, every other thing, and everything on top of that. It apparently isn't a trivial process for him to setup weaponry here on Meta, so it'll have to wait until the necessary time investment slot exists as usable time that doesn't take away from other pursuits. It may be on his plate far down the road.

Comment: By then, [a greyscale filter](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html) might make this a trivial one-liner… On second thought, nah, the W3C doesn't move that fast.