# The Memes of Arqade and its Chat

Tags: support, fun

> *In the style of [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)*

Catchphrases and concepts that spread from person to person are known as [memes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme_(Internet)), which, courtesy the internet, can now explode across the earth like a highly contagious virus (hence "going viral").  As with their IRL counterparts, some infectious diseases are global, while others are endemic to specific regions.

Here we try to catalog some of these pathological sociological constructs that taint the water in our humble corner of the internet, Arqade.

Comment: These are really all memes of Gaming.SE chat, they don't tend to show up on the site itself.

Comment: @bwarner Closest is [murder], or more accurately badp's comment on it, as that portion exists mostly within comments on here and the parent Q&A moreso than on the chat. Well, and GnomeSlice, since we don't actually chat all that much about his eccentricities. We have a bunch of Q&A-centric injokes (like how irritating it is to see Mana's face plastered on every other post), but I don't think any of that is really memetic yet.

Comment: ...no lazers? Honestly? Really? For serious, now?

Answer (score 105):

**Meme:** Questions that are absurd without context

**Originator:** Various

**Cultural Height:** As Often as Possible

**Background:**

- [How can I get my wife to stop nagging about a few murders?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39411/how-can-i-get-my-wife-to-stop-nagging-about-a-few-murders) [fable-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fable-3)
- [Can I pass out from excessive drinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/can-i-pass-out-from-excessive-drinking) [bioshock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock)
- [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) [nethack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nethack)
- [How can I keep monsters out of my nether regions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions) [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)
- [My children are useless. What should I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18376/my-children-are-useless-what-should-i-do) [kings-bounty-the-legend](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kings-bounty-the-legend)
- [Al Gore won't leave me alone. How do I unfriend him on Facebook?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158984/al-gore-wont-leave-me-alone-how-do-i-unfriend-someone-on-facebook) [south-park-the-stick-of-truth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-park-the-stick-of-truth)
- [How do I cook meth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/130335/52800) [payday-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payday-2)
- [Is it a bad idea to take drugs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158907/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-take-drugs) [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim)
- [How do I lick a plane?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162789/how-do-i-lick-a-plane) [goat-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goat-simulator)
- [How can I increase my chances of getting cancer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169544/how-can-i-increase-my-chances-of-getting-cancer) [the-binding-of-isaac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac)
- [How can I reliably find a police car?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169800/how-can-i-reliably-find-a-police-car) [watch-dogs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch-dogs)
- [One of my cooks died, how do I get rid of the corpse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167223/one-of-my-cooks-died-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-corpse) [prison-architect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prison-architect)
- [What is the fastest way to kill my family?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139127/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-kill-my-family) [papers-please](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papers-please)
- [Will sleeping with my sons wife have a negative effect on our relationship?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174371/will-sleeping-with-my-sons-wife-have-a-negative-effect-on-our-relationship) [crusader-kings-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusader-kings-2)

Comment: @badp - what do you mean 'we don't need the entire list of questions' ?

Comment: @Raven Exactly what it says on the tin. There's no need to have the global compendium of all the questions with slighty disturbing titles; just the best examples will do. Do we need a list of all the "ARDA IS A TERRIBLE MOD" jokes?

Comment: This is cute when it occurs naturally, but I feel like increased efforts to force questions to be funny when a less amusing wording would be more natural is causing some of the shine to rub off.

Comment: Also see [this question](//meta.arqade.com/q/2521/) for a good selection of absurd question titles:

Comment: @Bobson Or, we could all read badp's comment above, realize it's already bigger than it strictly needs to be, and stop editing it altogether. Maybe get a lock on the answer from a mod.

Answer (score 38):

**Meme:** GnomeSlice getting into trouble in Minecraft

**Originator:** [GnomeSlice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3114/gnomeslice)

**Cultural Height:** ?

**Background:**

- [I seem to have made a bit of an error in judgement.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/how-can-i-butcher-animals-en-masse)
- [I'm in a bit of a pickle.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20846/do-blasts-pass-through-obsidian)

**Related:**

Comment: +1 for ego boost.

Answer (score 36):

> In memory of murder:
>
> [A lot of us loved [tag:murder]. Even many of us who knew it was a terrible tag, we still found its application humorous and the concept gave us entertainment. We're sad to see it go, but we're enduring its loss so that we can pave a way to a much greater future.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2476275#2476275)

**Meme:** [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder) tag.

**Originator:**  [GnomeSlice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3114/gnomeslice).

**Cultural Height:**  Probably about [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=846003#846003).

**Murdered on:** [November 17th, 2011](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/whither-murder)

**Background:**

- [Can I kill everybody?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13892/can-i-kill-everybody) [deus-ex](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deus-ex)

  - I originally wanted to pop a quick joke on how it seems that everywhere I'll look on this site, I'll find a mass-murderer, but it seems that [I am indeed surrounded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Z8C.png) – Grace Note♦ [Jan 4 at 18:33](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13892/can-i-kill-everybody#comment-18887)
- [How do I poison someone?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14814/how-do-i-poison-someone) [die2nite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/die2nite)

Comment: The actual originator is Grace Note, with her comments about our friendly mass murderers in the community.

Comment: @badp As amusing as that is, I hadn't even seen/heard of that quip when I created the first [tag:murder] tag on my die2nite question.

Comment: I like [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/125834/42984) question for murder candidate.

Comment: [\[Tommy had to go away.\] We had a problem. We tried to do everything we could... You know what I mean. He's gone, and we couldn't do nothing about it.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Goodfellas)

Answer (score 28):

**Meme:** Lazers

**Originator:**

**Cultural Height:**
The Mass Effect 3 promotion, "ME3Missions", which gave us:

[image]

**Background:** See [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/ask-question-is-not-really-obvious-as-a-button/1212#1212).

**Special Shout-out**: Jin. For giving us Lazers <3

Comment: Why met doesn't do that?

Comment: Wow, arqade is amazing! I literally just joined for the lasers - wish other sites had such a cool "ask question" button.

Answer (score 27):

**Meme:** GnomeSlice getting into trouble with Autocomplete

**Originator:** GnomeSlice's [Funky Phone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20596703#20596703)

**Cultural Height:** Whenever GnomeSlice is [on the busty](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20660834#20660834) or [has cold fjords](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20774611#20774611).

**Cultural Height 2.0:** [Snacks in a place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttusA.jpg)

**Background:**

- [Back to wang](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20770607#20770607) / [Back to worm](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20560168#20560168)
- [Jesus crusty](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20774452#20774452)/ [Jesus cherish](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20885767#20885767)
- [@orgyrambo what? When did that happen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20774445#20774445)
- [GOD](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20774315#20774315) [DONUT](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20560051#20560051)
- [For duck shake](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20737534#20737534) / [For tuck bake](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21026981#21026981) / [Duck sale](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23762652#23762652)
- [Cats do savages the duck they wang](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20660788#20660788)
- [But green of words is like what autocorrect is debug to do appetizer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20661061#20661061)
- [Brb disemboweling bus](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20623831#20623831)
- [Spiders are just tiny burgers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20655920#20655920)
- [So I could go home and play blood boner](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20818189#20818189)
- [#aleaysfwsoy2mijtued (always wait 2 minutes)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20811063#20811063)
- [Rafter is apparently lynx the nudity time of year at a horse store](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=20885797#20885797)
- [vvvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbvvvvv](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=23762639#23762639)

Comment: As with the absurd title answer, every example doesn't need to be added here.  A dozen examples are more than enough.

Comment: I'll just leave @TimStone's masterpiece here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ttusA.jpg

Answer (score 26):

**Meme:** QA

**Originator:**  [Nick T](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4376663#4376663)

**Cultural Height:**  June 12th, when the site name 'Arqade' and new design were published.

**Background:**  Badp thought he was being [oh, so clever](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4934962#4934962).  Now look what you've done.  Half the chat has changed their name to include 'QA' in it somewhere.

Comment: I honestly never thought about the name like that.  I thought it was just trying to be cool by spelling "Arcade" weird.

Answer (score 24):

**Meme:** 
Wipqozn's law of gravitation.

> Every topic on The Bridge, must, inevitably, eventually return to Minecraft and TF2.

**Originator:** [Wipqozn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8350/wipqozn)

**Cultural height:** Whenever there's an active conversation on The Bridge

**Background:** http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1228881#1228881

Answer (score 22):

**Meme:** Arda is going to make a terrible mod

**Originator**: [Mana](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=446205#446205)

**Cultural Height**: Terrible

**Background**

- [The chat conversation that brought us this fundamental truth, and Arda's acceptance thereof.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/the-moment-of-epiphany-that-struck-mana-with-the-obvious-truth)

**Related**

- [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)

Comment: Ah, we will never have those stars back...

Comment: @Arda If it's any source of forgiveness, [this](http://i.imgur.com/fbrPs.png) is now my [workaround for certain interface issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/please-let-users-opt-out-of-the-frequented-tag-system).

Comment: +1 for ego boost. Another +1 for ripping off @GnomeSlice.

Comment: [Revived!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=26927738#26927738)

Answer (score 19):

**Meme:** Photoshopping Mana's avatar onto other photos

**Originator:** [Ronan Forman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4012/ronan-forman)

**Cultural Height:** http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2239295#2239295

**Background:** http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1425948#1425948

Comment: Every time I see that room full of Manas I think of [that scene from Being John Malkovich](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX9MtuqVrUQ&t=3m8s).

Answer (score 18):

**Meme:** Wipqozn has been removed from the list of this room's owners.

**Originator:** LessPop_MoreFizz

**Cultural Height:** Ongoing

**Background:**

Room owners in The Bridge derive a large amount of enjoyment from granting Wipqozn room ownership and then removing it soon after. This has recently [started leaking into other chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14095372#14095372).

- [Transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Wipqozn&user=-2&room=35)

Answer (score 17):

**Meme:** @OrigamiRobot (and others) accepting data

**Originator:** [@OrigamiRobot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=7870894#7870894)

**Cultural Height:** To date, the most-starred data message is: [`GNOMESLICE WANTS TO BE A BAD GIRL: DATA ACCEPTED`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=11196784#11196784)

**Background:** Originally, before the first datum was accepted, [commands](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4255743#4255743) and [factoids](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4989633#4989633) were accepted, although since the advent of data acceptance these reponses have not been seen again.

**Important Note:** The format for data messages is as follows:

```
[DATA TO BE REVIEWED IN ALL-CAPS]: DATA [STATUS OF DATA]
```

Comment: `@ORIGAMIROBOT APPROVES OF THIS MEME: DATA ACCEPTED`

Answer (score 16):

**Meme:** @Wipqozn is to blame

**Originator:** Spugsley (Wipqozn drove her to it because it is his fault, after all)

**Cultural Height:** Whenever there is real or imagined blame to be apportioned, and preferably with lots of pings to @Wipqozn while he is not in chat (thus summoning him in the middle of random <s>tortoise</s> turtle stuff)

[Proof by Sterno](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9tK0.jpg)

Answer (score 16):

**Meme:** "Good morning, Bridge"

**Originator:** @Frank

**Cultural Height:** Pretty much every morning when @Frank says "Good morning, Bridge" in chat and everybody stars it.

[Yes, it's really a thing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22good+morning%2C+bridge%22&user=34238&room=35)

Testimonials for the positive effects of "Good morning, Bridge": [1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13039299#13039299) [2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13039332#13039332) [3](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=13039466#13039466) [4](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=5933353#5933353) [5](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=12513174#12513174) [6](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=11823701#11823701)

Comment: I still don't know how that became an Arqade meme, but whatever.

Comment: I know I started it because of random, and then it became a thing.

Comment: I can't start my mornings anymore without "Good morning, Bridge".

Comment: I can't start my afternoon anymore without clearing stars on "Good morning, Bridge."

Comment: Other people have started it doing it now too. Kevin says Morning chat when he enters the room in the morning, other regulars join in and inevitably Lazers 2.0 breaks the combo. At one point, a user even used this Lazers combobreaker to wish Kevin good morning...

Answer (score 15):

**Meme:** kalina setting people on fire

**Originator:** [kalina](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=5673006#5673006)

**Cultural Height:** still kindling

**Related:** [Spreadsheet](http://fire.vad-systems.de/0) of people kalina has set fire to [in the Bridge](http://fire.vad-systems.de/35) ([2012](http://fire.vad-systems.de/35/2012), [2013](http://fire.vad-systems.de/35/2013), [2014](http://fire.vad-systems.de/35/2014))

Comment: links be dead :(

Answer (score 12):

**Meme:** Wipqozn

**Cultural Height:** [Wipqozn realises his memetic status](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18250245#18250245)

**Background:**  [This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2734/3610), [This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8464/3610),                        [This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5219/3610) & [This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2250/3610)

Comment: Wipqozn meme best meme.

Answer (score 11):

**Meme:** spugsley pls

**Originator:** [Mana](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4561742#4561742)

**Cultural Height:** Whenever dolan is being discussed or spugsley needs a pls.

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4606041#4606041
- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4644787#4644787

**Background:** [Mana was the first to stumble upon dolan.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4547523#4547523) [GnomeSlice saw it and linked spugsley to some Dolan comics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4547659#4547659) about a half hour later, but she initially ignored them. [Mana posted some more ~17 hours later](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4557821#4557821), but just bothered Fluttershy somewhat. [Then Mana posted them to spugsley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4561644#4561644), and discovered that [apparently she *really* hates them](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4561688#4561688). After about ten minutes of her having a mental breakdown, ["spugsley plz"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4561742#4561742).

Comment: You're forgetting the part where @Mana posted adorable pictures of puppies and then *changed all of them to dolan* after I said they were adorable. He's the worst person

Comment: @spugsley That sounds like it belongs under cultural height.

Comment: hey, I *invented* [spugly pls](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=spugly&Room=35&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) and, AND a [custom dolan](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zl2Ud.png) just to irritate her, so nyah.

Comment: Then there's [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10791197#10791197)

Answer (score 9):

**Meme:** [bacon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bacon)

**Originator:** [Powerlord](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/15880/powerlord)

**Cultural Height:** Not there yet

**Background:** http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=688689#688689

**Related:** [Is it dangerous to go extreme pig riding in a thunderstorm?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21261/concerns-about-extreme-pig-riding-and-thunderstorms)

Answer (score 9):

**Meme:** [John](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5029/john-the-green) being sad and saying :(

**Originator:** [John](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5029/john-the-green)

**Cultural Height:** Whenever John is in chat and Wipqozn is around to star the :(

**Background:**

- [OK SERIOUSLY IS @WIPQOZN FOLLOWING ME AROUND AND STARRING MY EVERY EXPRESSION OF DISMAY?!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=3074341#3074341)
- [I support @Wipqozn in his effort to star all of @John's :(](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3190829#3190829)

Comment: Shouldn't you just post a new answer?

Comment: @Ullallulloo I didn't feel like letting the bytes go to waste.

Comment: I lol'd. This made my day.

Answer (score 9):

**Meme:** Year of Wipqozn

**Originator:** [God-Emperor Dune](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50294110#50294110), [fredley](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50295840#50295840), and [Wipqozn](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50296470#50296470)

**Cultural Height:** [2019 Moderator election](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/6)

**Background:** [Ash](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/the-time-has-come-the-walrus-said-to-talk-of-many-things), [badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13350/diamond-combo-%C3%972), [StrixVaria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13355/oh-baby-a-triple), and [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13388/may-the-fourth-be-always-with-you) all turning in their diamonds in quick succession, leaving Arqade in the hands of none other than... Wipqozn.

Comment: To be fair @Robotnik was still around, but he's in crazy upside down Australia where its nighttime when the rest of the world is awake, so he's not able to stop my reign of terror.

Answer (score 7):

**Meme:** @OrigamiRobot is scared of sloths

**Originator:** [Pugsley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/11764/ian-pugsley)

**Cultural Height:** [@Sterno's offer?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10123157#10123157)

**Background:**  [@Origami's statement](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2911069#2911069) and [@Pugsley's response](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2911106#2911106)

**Assorted other examples:** [StrixVaria](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10046773#10046773), [blem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11631389#11631389), [fredley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11631751#11631751), [OragamiRobot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11352103#11352103), [FEichinger](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10685473#10685473)

Answer (score 3):

**Meme:** What is Love 10 Hours video.

**Originator:** [Wipqozn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1586648#1586648)

**Cultural Height:** Whenever someone feels like trolling Gnomeslice.

**Background:** [MsDugITBANI](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=MsDugITBANI&user=&room=35)

**EDIT :**  The original video (or at least, at [this URL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsDugITBANI)) is no longer available on Youtube.  Tragic.

Answer (score 1):

**Meme:** Ponies

**Originator:** [Wipqozn?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=1534493#1534493)
<sup>This is the earliest pro-pony post I can find, there might be earlier examples?</sup>

**Cultural Height:** Ongoing

**Background:** [So I heard you like ponies?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/so-i-heard-you-like-ponies) - Ponies created [fun](/questions/tagged/fun).
[PONIES](https://stackapps.com/questions/4344/ponies-hide-unwelcome-images-in-chat)
[Unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/150214)

Answer (score 1):

**Meme:** Freehand drawing

**Originator:** Various

**Cultural Height:** Ongoing

**Background:**

- [The Magic Card](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3786/42984)
- [Diablo 3 answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49977/42984)
- [Skyrim answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40280/42984)
- [Upvote bait](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11765789#11765789)

Comment: This one's [not really ours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775), we just tend to borrow it sometimes.