# So I heard you like Ponies

Tags: discussion, fun

After the people over at Hasbro made a My Little Pony animated series, I thought it would be fun to pon-ify some of the people here. They were apparently very popular (mostly) and people were asking for more. So here are some of the ponies I made.

If you want to make your own, just use [Pony Creator](http://generalzoi.deviantart.com/art/Pony-Creator-Full-Version-254295904) and go to town! The font I used is [Celestia Medium](http://www.mattyhex.net/CMR/).

Also, I can art. If you would like me to art, feel free to ask me for arts.

---

GROUND RULES

The goal of this kind of thing is for everyone to have fun and enjoy themselves. To that end we've come to agree with allowing it under the following circumstances, in addition to the standard rules explained in the [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) tag wiki.

1. Please do not make a ponification of a user without their permission.
2. Please do not make a ponification of a user with malicious or mocking intent. Even absent of such intent, if a user feels insulted or offended by their personal depiction, that depiction must be taken down.
3. Please be respectful of others in comments and do not turn this into pro-anti arguments about the subject matter.

Comment: *is sad there is no shanopony*

Comment: This post was originally closed by moderators after complaints about its intent, the nature of its material, and rowdy activity that occurred in the comments. The moderators have met and agreed to reopen it, as well as the [MtG thread](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/so-i-heard-you-like-magic-cards?rq=1), under some ground rules that are explained in the [fun tag wiki](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/fun/info) and also in the thread itself. Which mostly summarizes to, to quote agent86, "Be nice", but please do read them.

Comment: [Something went horribly horribly wrong](http://i.imgur.com/BMAfscD.png)...

Comment: @shanodin - I could put my elite (read:noobish) accessorising skills to work and make you one if you would like?

Comment: @shanodin - Well [here you go](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48802429/shanopony.png). I couldn't use your marshall badge, but look! a cape! That's *kinda* like a badge, but more awesome.

Comment: @Robotnik This is awesome. +1 ponies for you.

Comment: I have a cape! Yay! @Robotnik is the awesome ponymaker

Comment: @shanodin - glad you like it :)

Comment: @spartacus I see nothing wrong there. That's cute!

Comment: @fredley arts me!

Comment: @JeffreyLin [Your wish is my command](http://i.imgur.com/2nDB5E0.png)

Comment: @fredley - brilliant!

Comment: @fredley I am throughly disturbed. Don't take it down though.

Comment: Anyone want to do a Pony of me?

Comment: How has noone ponified @fredley??? On it now

Comment: @fredley - It is done. However, I need explicit permission to post as per rule 1. Yay or neigh? Pun absolutely intended

Comment: [@Robotnik](http://img-cache.cdn.gaiaonline.com/103d243e1aab607f66f9c2b6ff2a82f5/http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y157/whendouplan2goaway/YAY.png)

Answer (score 17):

[image: OrigamiRobot as a Pony]

Comment: Needs a top hat.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Your wish is my command

Comment: I CAN'T UPVOTE THIS ANY HARDER

Comment: OrigamiPony is best pony

Answer (score 9):

[image: Grace Note as a Pony]

Comment: Dat Flowing Mane!

Answer (score 9):

[image]

<sup>disclaimer: image by @fredley</sup>

Comment: I'm not actually that mean.  I don't know where anyone gets that impression.

Comment: @fbueckert You're just grumpy.

Comment: @fbueckert I find this representation totally accurate of you.

Comment: Needs a huge bushy beard and a suit tbh

Comment: In other words, @fbueckert should be a goat in a suit.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Wipqozn as a Pony]

Comment: I like this pony alot. :3

Answer (score 7):

[image: SevenSidedDie]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Shanodin

[image: shanopony]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: Easy on the coffee there, pal.

Answer (score 5):

My thanks to fredley for the textual additions

[image: Robotnik]

Answer (score 5):

[image: World Engineer is a pony]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: Hehe, awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: This pony is just a little terrifying.

Comment: Eye is too well-drawn.

Answer (score 2):

V2.0
[image: fredley]

Comment: I tried to capture the DP of cooked Minecraft meat

Comment: This looks poxed and awful.

Comment: @fredley - You're right. It was an experiment. v2 is up

Comment: Not shiny enough. I'm a *golden* porkchop.

Comment: Are those... legwarmers?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score -9):

[image: This is not me]

Comment: Who is this supposed to be?  We need labels!

Comment: @Wipqozn That's up for debate, I just wanted to make a pony.

Comment: (and I don't know how to do labels anyway)

Comment: @3ventic This pony worst pony.

Comment: @fredley It's always good to set the bottom line.