# A Terrible Mod Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators, status-murdered

The [time](http://supertimeforce.com/) has come for me to step down as a moderator of this site. I love this place and the community we've built up around it, but unfortunately my other responsibilities leave me with too little [time](http://supertimeforce.com/) to spend here these days.

I could reminisce about all the wonderful [times](http://supertimeforce.com/) we've had together, and about how I made my rise from lowly nobody to supreme ruler through so much careful and deliberate [political subterfuge](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2189/207), but instead I'm just going to use this space to let you know that you're all wonderful and bizarre people and I learned a lot from being around here. In particular, I gathered an [exceptional wealth of information](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=fanfic&room=35) for my upcoming romance fanfic.

Notable fanfic pairings:

- Spugsley x Dolan
- Gnomeslice x Wipqozn
- Wipqozn x Wipqozn
- [Garfield x Everyone](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/2097849/ShakespeareHemmingway)

On a more serious note, since I'm stepping down, the 4th place finisher in the previous mod election will be stepping up to take my place. Welcome to the team, [StrixVaria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1719/strixvaria)! He's the raddest guy around, and I know he'll do a fantastic job here, but is he a bad enough dude to rescue the president?

Well, I'll let him decide that.

So, yay! New mod! [Here's an inspirational quote](http://quoteseverlasting.com/quotations/famous-quotes/2013/01/Dont-cry-because-its-over-smile-because-it-happened.-Dr.-Seuss.jpg)! Until next [time](http://supertimeforce.com/), Arqade!

Comment: May I be the first to say: :(

Comment: AAAAAAAARGH! I forgot to check your final score before you left

Comment: I'm guessing he's working on a game.  Not 100% sure though. *cough*

Comment: I should probably make it clear that I'm not a Super Time Force dev, although I've met people from Capy a few times now. I just found [the ending cutscene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nQXn5V7CfI)(and this trend throughout the entire game) hilarious.

Comment: :( @fredley beat me to :(, so I am left with nothing but to say :( ⭐️

Comment: NOT GOOBY I HATE YOU I HAAAAATTTTEEEE YOU

Comment: @spugsley I FIXT IT ALL BETTER NOW.