# Welcome Dragonrage and Unionhawk to the Moderator Team!

Tags: discussion, moderators

As we’re sure you’ll remember, Arqade last held an election in [June 2019](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/6). Since then, the mod team has been working fairly heavily on a few activities that need moderator attention (community building being a core focus of ours). As such, we’ve discussed what to do with the workload, and thought we could use a little more help on our side of the fence.

Following discussions with the CM team, and after confirming their willingness to step up, we’re happy to announce that the two highest-scoring candidates that were not elected from the previous election: [Unionhawk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/20306/unionhawk) and [Dragonrage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/127901/dragonrage), will be joining the moderator team!

Please join us in thanking them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: Congratulations, fellows, and thanks for investing your time and efforts into 'moderation'! One question: what is "community building" in this context specifically?

Comment: @Joachim A few things, but essentially we wanted to grow the team to help us with things like [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13489/arqade-community-check-in-2019-a-call-for-input)  and [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14681/what-type-of-community-events-would-you-like-to-see).

Comment: Bold move, appointing a moderator who's Universally wrong. Seriously though congrats to @Unionhawk and @Dragonrage!

Comment: @fredley We needed someone to take all the blame for my mistakes.

Comment: Congrats you two, well deserved based on the previous election

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: That's why we elected you to be a moderator @Wipqozn! Uni is wrong and you are to blame, that's how it's always been! But congratulations to Ash's new sockpuppets!

Comment: Congrats guys. Good choice! :)

Comment: Can I ask why the decision was made to bypass the system and appoint candidates from the previous election? I'm assuming it was that the mod team preferred those candidates to uncertainty but if thats the case, why have elections at all? Why not embrace the mods appointed by mods oligarchy?

Comment: @Studoku Calling up mods from a past election is always an option, depending on how recent the last election was. We've actually done it before. In this case we decided to call on the runner ups from the previous election because it was only back in June, and a new election would've taken quite a while. Elections always take a while to spin up, but there's a lot of sites in line to have an election right now, so the wait would've been even longer than usual. If you're concerned about the mods we called up, then [I'll refer you to this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13468/8350).

Comment: @Wipqozn I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @Studoku Note that StrixVaria/InvaderSkoodge was called up when [Mana stepped down](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8652/28182)

Answer (score 26):

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on becoming a moderator! :)

Comment: I always see you contributing to Arqade's community. Glad to see you becoming a mod!

Answer (score 23):

[image: Oooh, Shiny. :)]

Comment: We are mining diamonds