# The time has come, the Walrus said, to talk of many things

Tags: discussion, moderation

....of shoes and ships and sailing wax, of cabbages and kings....

And also about how I'm stepping down as moderator, effective whenever the CMs see my request (tomorrow, probably, at this point).

It's not because I don't love y'all, because I do. I'm not leaving the site, I'm still going to be in chat (and still want to hear about the small brave and your work frustrations and all of the ways y'all are finding ways to love yourselves as you are, about video games you love or books you think I should read.) You're stuck with me. Sorry. (Not actually sorry.)

Life's just...changing a lot for me, and I have new adventures that need my attention and spoons. So...thanks, y'all, for letting me handle flags and make the internet a little better in this corner. Y'all are fantastic humans, and I love you more than I've got the ability to word.

Comment: I’m torn. I want to upvote this because you’re awesome but I want to downvote this because I hate to see the best mod on the site leave. :(

Comment: @GodEmperorDune `s/site/network/`

Comment: No disagreement here

Comment: It's a huge shame to see you off and SE's moderator corps will be left with an Ash-shaped hole in it. Don't be a stranger!

Comment: I know i have messed up alot and annoyed Ash wih my behaviour sometimes, but you will be missed!

Answer (score 23):

I, for one, will be sad to see you without your diamond, but I am glad you are staying around. When I first joined the site, you were one of the most friendly and helpful faces I found, and you helped me find my place in the community as well as gently guiding me to being a more positive and helpful member.

I cannot remember a time where you lost your temper or lashed out at someone. Thank you for all that you have done in service to the Arqade and its users as a mod, and thank you for leaving a great example to all members on how to not only be a stellar mod, but also a stellar person.

I wish you all the best in your new adventures in life.

Comment: Aww, dang, hun, you made me weepy. Thank you. <3

Answer (score 18):

## :(

I do have a tendency to waffle so to cut a long story short:

I don't think words can express just how much love Ash has given this site (both before and during the moderator years). I always considered you (and [badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13350/28182)) as the kind of mods to aspire to: passionate, fair, knowledgeable, patient... just all around good people and I hold myself to that same standard: *your* standard.

Jeff Atwood once said that mods are "[Ambassadors of trust](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)", I think it's fair to say that both of you earned that trust a thousand times over. Thanks for everything, and all the best for what the future holds!

Comment: Awww, thanks. I did love serving with you guys, you made it great fun.

Answer (score 16):

I know I speak on behalf of the entire mod team when I saw: **It's been an honour.** You've always gone above and beyond what was expected of moderators, and you'll be sorely missed. I wish you the best of luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: Thanks, turtle. You are good human.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had much time to interact with y'all as much as I wanted in Meta and chat, and honestly that hasn't changed, because I'm busier now than ever, but I did want to thank you for your effort. As I mentioned in Raven Dreamer's goodbye post, it takes integrity to admit when you're not doing as much for your role as you should be, and making the decision to step down. So on behalf of the would-be lurkers and not-as-involved-as-they-want-to-be people like myself, thank you for your service to the site. (and glad you're sticking around)