# Oh baby a triple!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm stepping down as a moderator of Arqade. I've been a lot less active of late, especially in moderation activities, and I want to make room for someone who will be active.

I'm not one for long-winded personal speeches, so here's the rundown.

- I still love this place.
- I'll still hang out in chat and stuff.
- I'm looking for literally any reason to ban somebody before they rip this diamond away from me.

Comment: We're falling like Dominoes right now

Comment: @Robotnik, thanos snapped :(

Answer (score 17):

It's been a pleasure serving with you kindest of sirs. I wish you the best in the future, and I'm certainly glad you'll still be sticking around in chat. Also, no matter how many times you change your name and avatar, you'll always be StrixVaria with a Gir avatar in my heart <3

Comment: ^all of this. Thanks for everything Strix/Skoodge :-)

Answer (score 15):

You now owe the internet oracle a version of this with Ash's and your avatar (or equivalent)

[image]