# Only one Hot Meta Post is showing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Arqade Meta has recently had three different posts that have attracted quite a bit of attention, announcing three beloved Arqade mods giving up their diamonds:

- [The time has come, the Walrus said, to talk of many things](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/the-time-has-come-the-walrus-said-to-talk-of-many-things)
- [</diamond> combo ×2](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13350/diamond-combo-%c3%972)
- [Oh baby a triple!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13355/oh-baby-a-triple)

Despite that, only one of these posts seems to appear under "Hot Meta Posts", both on main and Meta.

[image: The Hot Meta Posts box as it appears for me]

I'm assuming the system isn't aware enough to check that Ash's modship was already taken away, so this looks like a bug to me.

Just in case people are not aware, the Hot Meta Posts box is supposed to show recent meta posts with a net score of 3 or higher. And to confirm this is only an issue on Arqade, this is what the Hot Meta Posts box currently looks like on RPG.se:

[image: The RPG Hot Meta Posts box as it appears for me]

Comment: It's probably because the other two are tagged [support] not [discussion]. Edited InvaderSkoodge's one to use [discussion] for science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah it seems that [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions are excluded from 'Hot Meta Posts'. I would assume this is the case for [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) too.

Both badp and Invader Skoodge's posts used [support](/questions/tagged/support), while Ash's used [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). Editing Invader Skoodge's announcement to use [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) resulted in the question appearing under Hot Meta Posts after about an hour or so (its not immediate):

[image: Hot Meta Posts In Your Local Area]

Comment: Status: by design, I suppose!

Comment: Seems so! :-)  .