# May the Fourth be always with you!

Tags: discussion, moderators

So, [not like](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13348/336) [I'm jumping on](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13350/336) [a bandwagon](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13355/336) [or anything](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13388/336)...

But 'tis time for me to hang up my plumbob as well!

It would not surprise me if many of you have no idea who I am. That's okay. I regard you fondly all the same.

To keep things short and simple -- I've not been handling much of the moderator workload (for years, truly; Ash and Badp are/were literal flag-monsters), so I don't think my "departure" is going to have much of an effect!

I plan to continue to lurk and help in what small ways I can (gotta stay on top as long as I can, after all!), but I can do that just fine as a 20K+ rep user.

To say "Farewell" or "Au Revoir" would be hyperbolic -- so instead I say: **"Game on!"**

Comment: May your dreams be always peaceful, or something. Sad to see you retire. GL :)

Comment: Oh wow, a moderator whose name I actually recognise! "gotta stay on top as long as I can" Don't worry, if the trends of this month continue, you'll stay #1 for over 13 years, even if you completely stop acquiring points! Then Dulkan would overtake you, two months later agent86, then about 2 years later I would overtake you and 4½ years later than that Unionhawk. That's actually even more extreme than I thought before I started making this list. How in the world did you get so many points? I guess there's a reason why you're the only person with the "legendary" badge.

Comment: `Dwarf-Fortress` helped a bunch. Hahaha. And that's going to come out on steam soon, so perhaps there'll be a Renaissance!

Comment: Get your game on! Throwin down a face down.

Comment: Kinda half-joking, half-serious question: Is there something going on behind the scenes that we have four mods retire within a two week time period, or is it sheer coincidence? Just seems really bizarre, lol. Anyway, congrats on the retirement!

Comment: We were told that we were close to a record and decided to go for broke. /s

Answer (score 13):

It's been great serving with you sir, and you'll be missed. Don't be a stranger now though, because Icebourne is approaching... You'll need to play it on one of those 50 TV's you won back in the day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your hard work to the site! As with other relatively recent mod departures, it's good to see the integrity of knowing when you can't fulfill the role and stepping down. Best of luck to you!